# Google Map Display For Full UK Postcode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a website where each user input's their full UK postcode because I want to show their location on a map. I did this a few years ago for some local business clients but for some reason now I can't find how to do it. I don't want anything complicated with geo-locations or anything like that, just a simple code snippet similar to:

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=POSTCODEHERE&zoom=14&size=200x200&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:ORANGE|label:A|POSTCODEHERE&sensor=false" style="float: right">
```

Except the user can drag the map location. Anyone know the code for this?

Comment: So you want the user to be able to drag or not? - If not then your code works - http://jsfiddle.net/DTDag/

Comment: That's what I said, I want them to be able to move around the map and to zoom in / out if necessary

Comment: A static map is by definition static (not draggable).  You either want a link to an embedded [Google Map](http://maps.google.com) or to use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).  This [example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) can be modified to do what you want.

Comment: There are licensing issues when using postcode info with live maps. Although people have work-around solutions using Google's search API.

Comment: Thanks@geocodezip - I've tried playing around with the code in your second example link but I can't quite get it to do what I want. How would I make this map show up on page load? I have an input box with the postcode on the page

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?